# Boostrap 4 dropdown open in wrong position

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, dropdown

[image]

Hi,

I am using laravael and i am trying to render a bootstrap dropdown from the file **a**.blade.php to the file **b**.blade.php.

The dropdown renders but in a wrong position. See image attached. Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my code:

- file a.blade.php

  ```
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto main-search justify-content-end">
          <div class="input-group main-seach-field">
              <form action="{{route('frontend.search')}}" method="GET" class="search-form">
                  <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control"
                         placeholder=" &#xF002; {{__('polls.frontend.search-placeholder')}}"
                         style="font-family: Roboto, FontAwesome"/>
                        <div class="input-group toggle-search pr-1">
                          <div class="dropdown-toggle" href="" id="poll-search-modal" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" data-target="#poll-search-modal"
                         aria-expanded="false">
                      </div>
                   </div>
                  <input type="submit" value="{{__('polls.frontend.search.main-search')}}"  class="btn-search " />
              </form>
          </div>
      </ul>
  ```
- file a.blade.php

  ```
  <div class="nav-item dropdown  dropdown-advance-search" id="poll-search-modal">     
  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-advance-search dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="poll-search-modal">
           content here[![enter image description here][1]][1]
  </div>
  </div>
  ```

Comment: Are you talking about a drop-down or a modal? Post the *output HTML* for the a.blade.php and the b.blade.php

Answer (score 0):

This is not a laravel problem, but layout, try setting the menu position separately using styles